# ¿Porque no puedo ejecutar un SP de sql en python?

Tags: python, mysql

¿Que se busca? Ejecutar un sp de mysql en una linea de python y obtener sus registros.
¿Que se tiene? El código de python es el siguente:

```
self.con=conexionMySQL()
self.cursor=self.con.cursor()
insertCall = "insert into llamadas (`idUser`, `idSucursal`, `codeEmpCall`, `status`) values ('8', '"+str(self.insHome.informacion[message.chat.id]["_SUCURSAL_"])+"', '"+self.insHome.informacion[message.chat.id]["_COD_EMP_"]+"', '2') "
self.cursor.execute(insertCall)
self.con.commit()  
idCall = self.cursor.lastrowid
self.cursor.close()
self.con.close() 

idUsuarioAsignado=8
idUserAuxiliarAsignado = 8
queryNuevo = "call spSegundo(now()) "
self.cursor.execute(queryNuevo )
```

¿Que sucede? LA consola muestra una error con "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements"
¿Que se intento? Se activo el parametro multi=True para permitir multilinea, sin emgargo, cuando se activa, a pesar que ahora no falla, el resultado del registro es 0, aunque al ejectuarlo manual end DB si trae registros.

Asumi que el sp podria tener multiples lineas y ese era el error, reduge el query a lo siguiente :

```
 SELECT t.*, u.nickname FROM turnos t INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.idUser = t.idUserAsigned WHERE (t.idTask = 1 OR t.idTask=2) AND t.shilftdate = fechaProyeccionSPParam AND  ((DATE_FORMAT(fechaParametroSP, '%H:%i:%s') >= t.startTimeTask AND DATE_FORMAT(fechaParametroSP, '%H:%i:%s') <= t.endTimeTask)  or (DATE_FORMAT(fechaParametroSP, '%H:%i:%s') >= t.starLunchCover AND DATE_FORMAT(fechaParametroSP, '%H:%i:%s') <= t.endLunchCover));
```

Como dato curioso, se codigo de python fue extraido de un proyecto ya funcionando en un servidor el cual no falla. La version de mysql connector es la misma en mi equipo y en el server (8.0.23)